# how to use instantiateItem() in viewpager to update pages

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i update view when fragment change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687280/how-can-i-update-view-when-fragment-change)

have a activity that have 2 fragment in this The first two pages display fragments with custom list views which are built from xml from server using AsyncTask. However, when the app runs, only one list view is displayed, the other page is just blank

what can i use this method to update this pager

```
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
```

and my adapter code is

```
public class VpiAbsTestActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "1","2"};

TestFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
 ViewPager mPager;
 PageIndicator mIndicator;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
mIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();
}



class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {        
private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position) {

    case 0:
        return new customlist();


    case 1:
        return new customlistnotuser();


    default:
        return null;

    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
}


public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return VpiAbsTestActivity.CONTENT[position %             VpiAbsTestActivity.CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
}

 @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
         ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are asking for. As far as updating is concerned. `instantiateItem(View container, int position)` will be called when new page is required. So if you want to use this to update, delete the previous page > make changes > instantiate again with this

Comment: thnx my problem is this what can i do ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687280/how-can-i-update-view-when-fragment-change